Show value function in an angular template
Im trying to do a sum of a value od¿f an array that array is getting from a htto get method and a subscribe and im trying to show the result in the htm but dosent works
I hope somebody can help me with this coz im getting stock
here is my ts file:
result:any
getSumFacture(){
let total: number
this.http.get(this.url).subscribe((data:any) =>{
this.products = data
    total = this.products.reduce((sum: any, current: { totalPrice: any; }) => sum +       current.totalPrice, 0);
    console.log(total);
    
      return total
    });      
  }

and here is my html file
 {{result}}

You have to use the async pipe because the http call returns a Promise :
<div>{{result |async }}</div>


you trying to say i have to make the function async await?

No, just add the async pipe in the HTML template
